# Godot: area_entered() signal not fired for overlapping areas

Tags: collision-detection, area, godot, overlapping

I have a highlighter Area2D that snaps to the tilemap grid (think of a flashlight pointing to a specific tile), and I would like to have it detect which area is currently highlighted using the area_entered() and area_exited() signals:

```
# Highlighter.gd

extends Area2D

var highlighted_area

_on_Highlighter_area_entered(area):
    highlighted_area = area

_on_Highlighter_area_exited(area):
    highlighted_area = null
```

This is working as intended, except when I move from one area to an overlapping area. In that case the exiting signal fires but the entering signal for the adjacent (overlapping) area DOES NOT fire, hence **highlighted_area** will be stuck with null. See figure below:

[image]

Why is the enter signal not fired for overlapping areas? Any ideas how to get the signals to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the `monitoring` and `monitorable` properties of the `Area2D`.

Also, be aware that you are only storing one area in the script. Thus, if it has one area registered, and another area enters, it will override the first one. Furthermore, if one area exists, you will have null, even if there are still areas overlapping.

You could, of course, keep an array of currently overlapping areas.

---

However, I want to suggest something different. If you want to find out what is on a given point, you can use [`intersect_point`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html?#class-physics2ddirectspacestate-method-intersect-point). Example:

```
var space = get_world_2d().direct_space_state
var mouse_pos = get_global_mouse_position()
var results = space.intersect_point(mouse_pos, 32, [], 2147483647, false, true)
for result in results:
    print(result.collider)
```

Here we are asking for at most `32` collisions, with no exclusion (`[]`), on every layer (`2147483647`), excluding bodies `false`, and including areas `true`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for making me aware of intersect_point! Looks like it was made for exactly this use case, and like you pointed out it is better too as it can return an entire stack of areas the mouse is hovering over, which would likely have been my next problem. Will give it a try!